# Specify path in tsconfig.json instead of using relative path : ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts: error TS2307: Cannot find module '@...'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to resolve the relative path imports for component using the `path` property of `tsconfig.json`. But, it gives the below error. Not sure, why it giving this error. May it due to that `src/components` folder is not inside the `src/app` folder ?

**Actual Error :**

```
ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(12,33): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@advent/components'.
```

**1) This is my folder structure :**

```
src
  - app 
      - app.module.ts
      - app.component.ts
      - app.component.html
      - app.component.css
  - components
      - modals
          - modals.component.ts
          - modals.component.html
          - modals.component.css 
      - index.ts
tsconfig.json
```

**2) tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@advent/components/*": [
        "components/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**3) index.ts**

```
export * from './modals/modals.component';
```

**4) modals.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'modals',
  templateUrl: './modals.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modals.component.scss']
})
export class ModalsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**5) app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

// Importing Components
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ModalsComponent } from '@advent/components';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ModalsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 2):

Update below line in tsconfig.json

1. If **tsconfig.json** file is located in **src** folder and baseUrl = **"."**

```
"@advent/components/*": [ "./components/*" ]
```

2. If **tsconfig.json** file is located outside **src** folder and baseUrl = **"."**

```
"@advent/components/*": [ "./src/components/*" ]
```

3. If **tsconfig.json** file is located outside **src** folder and baseUrl = **"./src"**

```
"@advent/components/*": [ "./components/*" ]
```

Comment: as tsconfig.json file is located outside src folder, . Need to know as in tsconfig.json, baseUrl: './src'. so Is it required to consider './src' in "@advent/components/*": [ "./src/components/*" ] ?

Comment: @solanki... If the baseUrl is "./src" then "./src" is not required in paths value. Thanks I have updated my answer.

Comment: as per your answer, my folder structure is according to point 3. I used it, but it did not work. I got error : ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(12,33): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@advent/components'.

Comment: @solanki... can you please create simple module on https://stackblitz.com/ for reference?

Comment: @solanki...As you are exporting all components from index.ts file, update path to "@advent/components": [ "./components" ] in tsconfig.json file 

and also update styleUrls of modals.component.ts to "modals.component.css" for "ng serve" successfully run

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. Let me check and get back to you .